# Parity crashes after not closing cleanly

Tags: solidity, remix

If Parity doesn't close properly, I get the following error and have to resynch the entire chain again...

> thread '' panicked at 'Error opening state db: Failed to create
>   rocksdb directory: Error { repr: Os { code: 17, message: "File exists"
>   } }', util/src/journaldb/archivedb.rs:49 note: Run with
>   `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.

Has anyone got a better solution to recover in these instances?

Comment: I had a similar issue with failed database version migration. I never found out a solution other than removing the whole corrupted DB.